# Azure Releases, ACR Artifact not authenticating when using federated identity

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-container-registry, federated-identity

I have been using Azure releases and I have been using a ACR docker image as an artifact input.

Recently I noticed, that when trying to update one of my existing release pipelines I am getting the error below. This is happening since I migrated the Service Connection (type: Azure Resource Manager) to federated identity (previously they were using clientID and ClientSecret). This service connection does work for sure because I am using it in many places in order to push docker images. The service principal also has Contributor rights and ACRPush Role.

Can you please help? Is this some bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
Failed to query service connection API: 'https://xxx.azurecr.io/v2/_catalog'. Status Code: 'Unauthorized', Response from server: '{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.","detail":[{"Type":"registry","Name":"catalog","Action":"*"}]}]}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Chiming in just to say that I can also reproduce, so this is not an isolated thing. I'm switching our service connection back to a service principal.

Comment: Hi @Michele, have you checked my answer below? Do you follow the ticket in Developer Community and try to use the service principal in ARM SC?

Comment: Hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT Yes, I have checked and it I confirm it does work. However I would like to know when it will be fixed given 1) Microsooft has been recommending to move to this newer federated identity method. 2) Although SP does work from a devops perspective, it requires more management work (keys need to be recycled) 3) Tokens makes the system more insecure since they can be compromised

Comment: @Michele, I understand your concern. The ticket mentioned in my answer has been reported to the Azure DevOps product team. For your questions, you can ask directly on that ticket to let the product team hear your voice and know the impact of the issue more clearly. They will determine the priority based on the number of votes and comments on the ticket. Besides, you can [report a new bug in the Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/report) with the detailed description based on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue when using workload identity federation in ARM service connection. But it works fine when using service principal with the same permissions and roles.

I notices that there is already [a ticket in Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cant-access-to-ACR-after-switch-to-Work/10533151?sort=newest) reporting the same problem and has been reported to the product team. You can follow this ticket and add some comment to let the product team know the impact of the issue.

As a workaround, it's suggested that you could use service principal in ARM service connection temporarily.